# Webcam with circular fishey

Tags: webcam

I'm looking for a wireless wifi webcam with a uncropped circular fisheye lens. The only one I can find is D-Link DCS-6010L, but it is way too expensive. In theory it should be possible to buy a more basic web cam without fisheye and buy a separate fisheye lens. But it's not easy to find a good combo for this. No webcams I can find has mountings for other lenses and it seem very hard to know on before hand what lens matches what web cam in terms of size and angle etc.

Does anyone have experience with this? Any suggestions or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheapest solution: get the lens out of a door panel peephole and fabricate a mount in front of the webcam lens.  A cheap webcam with small diameter lens will work best for this, and the mount doesn't need to be sophisticate or pretty, just centered.  You may not get a full frame image, but the cost to find out is under $10 plus the cheap webcam (another $10 from some sources).

Second option, many webcams with manual focus lenses have threads compatible with C mount movie camera lenses; you can probably find one of those with the wide field you want for $10 to $50 on eBay.  I'll leave it as an exercise how to dismount the webcam lens and verify the thread is compatible...